# Using Vectors with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qvector

I seem to be having an issue using basic vectors in Qt, where I keep getting a compile error. The exact information will be posted below:

Code snippet:

```
....
#include <QVector>
#include <QString>

QVector<QString> vector;
vector.append("sometext");
```

Error message:

```
'vector' does not name a type
```

This error appears for any piece of code that directly pertains to the created vector, not just the append function. Any insight to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated. The vector exists. I've tested it by initializing all of it's elements using one item and accessing it in other parts of the program.

Comment: The code is fine. The cause is somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe use a new name other than `vector`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QString>

QVector<QString> vector;
vector.append("sometext");
```

If this is your real code, then you are doing the `append` outside of any function, which you can't do in c++, and which will cause the exact compilation error you mentioned:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is precisely the case. My professor neglected to express something so simple. I will accept this answer as soon as this website enables me to do so.

Comment: Fix: `QVector<QString> vector(1, "sometext");`. If you need more values, you need C++11: `QVector<QString> vector { "one", "two", "three" };`